# How does CSS formatting in a Google Maps bubble work?

Tags: css, google-maps, kml

I'm using KML and the GGeoXml object to overlay some shapes on an embedded Google map. The placemarks in the KML file have some custom descriptive information that shows up in the balloons.

```
<Placemark>
    <name />
    <description>
        <![CDATA[
            <div class="MapPopup">
                <h6>Concession</h6>
                <h4>~Name~</h4>
                <p>Description goes here</p>
                <a class="Button GoRight FloatRight" href="#"><span></span>View details</a>
            </div>
        ]]>
    </description>
    <styleUrl>#masterPolyStyle</styleUrl>
    ...Placemarks go here ...
</Placemark>
```

So far so good - the popups show up and have the correct text in them. Here's the weird thing: I'm trying to use CSS to format what goes in the popups, and it halfway works.

Specifically:

- The `<h6>` and `<h4>` elements are rendered using the colors and background images I've specified in my stylesheet.
- Everything shows up in Arial, not in the font I've specified in my CSS.
- The class names seem to be ignored (e.g. none of the `a.Button` formatting is applied; if I define a style like the one below, it's ignored.)

  ```
    div.MapPopup { background:pink; }
  ```

Any ideas? I wouldn't have been surprised for the CSS not to work at all, but it's weird that it only partly works.

#### Update

Here's a screenshot to better illustrate this. I've reproduced the `<div class="MapPopup">` markup further down on the page (in yellow), to show how it should be rendered according to my CSS.

[image]

Comment: Can you post an example online? It may be easier to debug if there's something we can go to.

Comment: Have you inspected the element with Firebug? It will show you which classes are being applied and from which file/line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested I've gone in with Firebug to see what's going on. It looks like Google is doing two obnoxious things:

1. It's stripping out all class attributes from my HTML.
2. It's throwing all kinds of hard-coded styles around.

Here's my HTML along with the first couple of wrappers inserted by Google:

```
<div style="font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: small;">
    <div id="iw_kml">
        <div>
            <h6>Concession</h6>
            <h4>BOIS KASSA 1108000 (Mobola-Mbondo)</h4>
            <p>
                Description goes here</p>
            <a target="_blank"><span />View details </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, my classes (e.g. `MapPopup` in my first `div`, `Button` etc. in the `<a>` tag) have all been stripped out.

Knowing this I'll be able to work around Google's interference, using `!important` and targeting the container `div` for the whole map - still, this is annoying, and unexpectedly clumsy coming from Google.

Answer (score 2):

More related obnoxiousness related to the HTML in a KML `<description>` block: Any links are given the attribute `target="_blank"`, whether you like it or not. I'm currently exploring ways to undo that, using jQuery, but what a drag. I really don't understand why Google feels the need to tamper with this HTML.

See also [this thread on the official Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API/browse_thread/thread/455e75b2c4549ab2/517f48eefbae46cb).

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues. I don't know how you are implementing your Marker, or if you are using InfoWindow, or .addListener, but they way I have had to get css styling to work inside of the "pop up bubble" (over the Marker) is to use what is called "inline styling." So I have a variable that I pass into InfoWindow. Assuming you have initialized a variable "marker" with some options, and have the "map" instance created, some example code would look like this:

```
/*start of myHtml2 variable*/
var myHtml2 = "<div style=\"background-color:lightgray\"><div style=\"padding:5px\"><div
style=\"font-size:1.25em\">Some text</div><div>Some more text<br/>
Yet more text<br/></div><table style=\"padding:5px\"><tr><td><img src=\"A lake.jpg\"
width=\"75px\" height=\"50px\"></td><td>More text<br/>Again, more text<br/><div
style=\"font-size:.7em\">Last text</div></td></tr></table></div></div>"
/*end of variable*/

var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: myHtml2});
 /*mouseover could be 'click', etc.*/
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(){  
infowindow2.open(map, marker);
});
```

I know the css styling code is cumbersome, but I haven't found a way to use complicated css styling inside "the bubble pop up" using css in the head, or from a style sheet There are always conflicts, and some features don't render properly.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you're running into an issue with CSS specificity. There is a good article on it at http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/, so if you can include a container element ID, that *may* help.

Let me know if this doesn't turn out to be the problem and I'll come up with more ideas.

Comment: No, I don't think that's right. For example: the `<div class="MapPopup">` should have a yellow background - that's not an issue of specificity.

Comment: I've never had a problem with styling, and the fact that only some styles are applied leads me to believe they are being overridden by other styles. 

As Zack suggested above, inspect the element with Firebug and see what's really affecting the font, etc.