# Google Maps Bubble Templates

Tags: google-maps

Googling has been difficult because I can't get results specific enough - wondering if my fellow SO-ers have any insight. Are there any handy CSS/HTML templates out there to make inserting content into a google maps bubble easy? I'm throwning together a quick-n-dirty mashup and wanted to avoid spending time styling manually if I can avoid it.

For reference, this post is somewhat related and could prove helpful:

- [how-does-css-formatting-in-a-google-maps-bubble-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203477/how-does-css-formatting-in-a-google-maps-bubble-work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't seen any templates for GInfoWindows, but they're not too hard to style.  Just put all your window content in a div with a class that you can reference in your stylesheets.

If you're looking for more customization than that, here are a few third-party extensions that provide an alternative to the standard GInfoWindows: [ExtInfoWindow](http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/extinfowindow/), [PopupMarker](http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/popupmarker/), [EWindow](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/ewindows.htm), and [EBubble](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/ebubble.htm)