# How to force the GInfoWindow to shorten its tail?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, openinfowindowhtml

In my Google Maps application, which is supposed to be run on mainly on iPhones, hence the 480/320 window resolution, I am displaying some "stuff" in the GInfoWindow information bubbles. The problem is that, sometimes the bubble is too filled with contents that it doesn't fit onto the screen quite the way I'd like it to.

Here's an example

[Too big a bubble http://www.perhac.com/Capture.PNG](http://www.perhac.com/Capture.PNG)

It's not exactly a catastrophe, but as in this case, the marker was pushed slightly off screen and the top of the bubble is not completely displayed too. But then I noticed the "tail" of the bubble (connects the info window to the marker) is toooooooo long.

Does anyone know of a simple way of making it shorter? Is there some property in `GInfoWindowOptions` that could help me with this? I don't thing `pixelOffset` is the way to go...

**Edit**

---

This is going to make the question awfully long, but I want you to notice that in the images downloaded from Google, there *is* a short tail, AND its short shadow... That's why I still believe there must be a way of using that one...

[image: bubble image]

[image: shadows]

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I'd like to display iPhone style GinfoWindow's but there does not seem to be an available option to do so in the openInfoWindowHTML function. Anybody solve this one?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are [no options to shorten the infoWindow tail](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GInfoWindowOptions).

You are correct that pixelOffset is not what you are looking for.  It is the equivalent of setting the infoWindowAnchor offset resulting in the same length tail, but pointing at a point offset (presumably downscreen) from your icon.  So you can move the window using this approach (as long as you use map.openInfoWindowHtml, not supported in marker.openInfoWindowHtml), but the tail pointing to something below your icon looks pretty average.

I hope I have missed something here and someone can correct me.

Alternatively, it would be great if this feature was implemented.  I feel like pixelOffset should do this, as you can already offset the infoWindowAnchor when you create the icon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I am still not quite convinced that it's not possible. When I take a look at the View "Page Info >> Media" and at the individual images downloaded from Google, there seems to be a "short tail" AND its short shadow as well... confusing.

Comment: It does look like it should be supported.  I wonder if it is just something that isn't exposed ?

Answer (score 0):

The short tail in that image is used for [maximized](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GInfoWindow.enableMaximize) infoWindow's.  There isn't any way to use it for a regular infoWindow.

A good alternative would be to use a third-party infoWindow.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262504/google-maps-bubble-templates/1080229#1080229) for a list of several options.