# Google Maps: How to add HTML elements to specific coordinates?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, overlay, google-maps-markers

I would like to know how and if I can add standard HTML elements (div, button) to a specific set of coordinates on the map ?

For example I have a set of coordinates and I would like to attach a custom balloon notification to them

[image: Google Maps with custom styled element attached to a set of coordinates]

and when I pan away from the coordinates the element should disappear and when I pan back to them, the element should reappear.

Is it possible to do this with Google Maps ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use custom overlays - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays for that

Comment: Is the bounds property required for all overlays? Is it possible to center the overlay on a single pair of lat+lng coordinates (i.e. from a marker)?

Answer (score 3):

As roman said, you can create a custom javascript object which implements [GOverlay](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/overlays.html#Custom_Overlays).

Here's an example from another S.O. question where the guy wanted to insert an SVG on top of a google map. However I am pretty sure you could use his solution to just insert HTML.

[How can I overlay SVG diagrams on Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055367/overlay-svg-diagrams-on-google-maps#answer-1083207)

Answer (score 1):

If you want make a custom balloon, see this question:

[Google Maps Bubble Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262504/google-maps-bubble-templates/)

Comment: I don't want to display only notification windows (bubbles). Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

What you want to look at is the [`openInfoWindowHtml`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2.openInfoWindowHtml) function.  You will need to add a [marker](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMarker) to the map first.  Check out [this example](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/megawindow/maxcontent_simple.html) on Google for a good example of this, combined with the nifty maximize function.

Comment: What I need is to add a plain HTML element to some coordinates on the map, not inside a Google Maps native notification window. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://gist.github.com/Eccenux/e0f411f9291761534028) as a base class for the latest Google Maps API version (v3):

Usage:

```
var rectBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.478490, 18.550357),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.478434, 18.551952)
);
var obj = new overlayText(rectBounds, 'Some<br />HTML', objGMap3);
```